# How to update the SWDAP firmware?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, debugging, probe, lpc

### 1. About the SWDAP probe

I bought an **SWDAP** probe some time ago from L-Tek (see https://www.l-tek.com/web-shop/l-tek-swdap-interface/). It took me some time to figure out the terminology, but I learned that:

- `CMSIS-DAP` is a standard defined by ARM. All probes that comply with this standard can flash and debug ARM target chips.
- `SWDAP` is an open-source probe, built by ARM. In fact, it's a reference hardware-implementation of the above mentioned standard. The SWDAP is sold by L-Tek and is based on a NXP `LPC11U35` chip. (See https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-HDK-Eagle-Projects/tree/master/DAPLink/Probes/SWDAP).
- `DAPLink` is an open-source firmware (written by ARM) that runs on the SWDAP probe. It is the reference software-implementation of the above mentioned standard. (See https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink).

[image]

---

### 2. Firmware update

I would like to update the firmware on my **SWDAP** probe. In other words, I want to flash the latest **DAPLink** firmware to my **SWDAP** probe.

I don't see a proper explanation how to do this.

**2.1 First try**
**-----------------**
I found the following webpage:
https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/DAPLink-bootloader-update/ 
But this webpage is a two year old blogpost. The binaries it links to are certainly deprecated.

**2.2 Second try**
**----------------------**
Thank you @RonBeyer for your answer. I clicked on your link (https://os.mbed.com/platforms/SWDAP-LPC11U35/) and noticed there are indeed some *Prebuilt Images* (binaries), but only for:

- NXP K64F
- NXP LPC1768
- Nordic nRF51822
- Multitech xDOT

Unfortunately, the NXP `LPC11U35` is not in that list. Anyhow, I downloaded all of the binaries, and guess what their names are:

- NXP K64F => `lpc11u35_swdap_k64f_if_crc.bin`
- NXP LPC1768 => `lpc11u35_swdap_lpc1768_if_crc.bin`
- Nordic nRF51822 => `lpc11u35_swdap_nrf51822_if_crc.bin`
- Multitech xDOT => `lpc11u35_xdot_l151_if_crc.bin`

So this confuses me even more. I have no idea which binary I should flash to the probe.

**2.3 Third try**
**------------------**
Thank you @RonBeyer for clarifying the naming convention of these binaries:

> `[Version]` _ `[Probe Chip]` _ `[Target Chip]`_ `[Offset]`.bin

Also many thanks for pointing out the webpage where to find the latest binaries for the SWDAP probe:

> https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/releases
>   <sub>From the releases page, just scroll down a little bit until you see ">Assets" right under the "notes" part and expand that. You will see a download link for the release.</sub>

It seems natural to have a different binary per **Probe Chip**. But it is striking to have different binaries for the **Target Chips**, especially because the SWDAP probe aims to work for all ARM targets (all targets that follow the CMSIS-DAP standard). Therefore, I developed my own theory about this thing:

- If you want a general SWDAP probe, take the binary without `[Target Chip]` in the name. So for my probe that would be `0254_lpc11u35_0x0000.bin` with `0254` being the version nr, `lpc11u35` the probe chip and `0x0000` the standard offset. The drag-and-drop feature* from this general SWDAP probe doesn't work. But if you use OpenOCD to flash the target, then it will always work.
- If you want to use the drag-and-drop feature*, then choose the binary that corresponds to your specific target chip.

<sub>* The drag-and-drop feature makes the SWDAP probe appear as a MSD (Mass Storage Device) when you plug it into your computer. To flash the target chip, you simply have to drag-and-drop the binary file to that MSD.</sub>

This is just a theory of mine. Please help if you got more insight into the matter.
**EDIT:** Apparently, this theory is correct. Thank you @ChrisReed to clarify that ^_^

So...
Now that I finally got the right binary file `0254_lpc11u35_0x0000.bin` I am totally ready to flash it to the probe.

**STEP 1**
I plug in the probe while holding the reset button down. As soon as it is plugged in, Dropbox pops up and asks me to import stuff. I click **No**, but it makes me hopeful that some kind of storage device is recognized. I open the Windows File Explorer, and I see the "CRP Disabled" device:

[image]

**STEP 2**
Only now that I see the "CRP Disabled" device, I dare to release the reset button on the SWDAP probe. I click on the "CRP Disabled" device to see its contents:

[image]

**STEP 3**
I delete the `firmware.bin` file from the probe (but I first save a backup of it somewhere on my computer). And yes, I am sure:

[image]

**STEP 4**
I copy-paste the new firmware `0254_lpc11u35_0x0000.bin` to the probe:

[image]

**STEP 5**
I plug out the probe, and plug it back in (this time not touching the reset button). The first time I did this, I got a little Windows announcement in the right down corner that **CMSIS-DAP** was being installed. But from the second time onward, that announcement no longer appears. However, I can see the device in:
Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers

[image]

**STEP 6**
I connect the SWDAP probe to my target board (a small board with a STM32F767ZI microcontroller). Now I run OpenOCD to flash a binary to the target chip. It doesn't work!
I use the exact same OpenOCD commands that I used before updating the SWDAP firmware. It used to work before that update. But now it fails over and over again. I get the following error from OpenOCD:

> Error: `CMSIS-DAP` command `CMD_INFO` failed.

**2.4 Restore original firmware**
**------------------------------------------**
Luckily I had taken a backup from the original `firmware.bin` on the probe. I now follow the steps described above again, this time to restore the original firmware.

To my great relief, I can again flash my target board using OpenOCD.

---

### 3. Conclusion

With the help from @RonBeyer and @ChrisStratton, I managed to flash the **SWDAP** probe with the latest **DAPLink** firmware `0254_lpc11u35_0x0000.bin`. Unfortunately, this causes the probe to malfunction with OpenOCD. Luckily I had kept a backup from the original firmware on the probe. Restoring that backup brings the probe back to live.

The purpose of this question is fulfilled: I can flash new firmware to the probe. The new problem that arised is about the firmware itself. I've opened a separate question for that problem: [DAPLink firmware doesn't operate with OpenOCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465577/daplink-firmware-doesnt-operate-with-openocd)

### 4. Notes

Thumbs up for ARM, and for @ChrisReed who replied very quickly on my GitHub issue that I raised on DAPLink! He clarified to me that all binaries with a specific "target chip" in the name should actually work for all target chips, provided that you don't use the drag-and-drop functionality.

---

Comment: As the documentation isn't making any sense, you probably need to either ask the vendor or figure it out yourself from the linked github sources.

Comment: Why specifically do you need to update the firmware?   Does it already work?  If not, what change are you hoping for?  How does the board currently identify itself when connected to a PC?

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, right now the probe works just fine. But I want to know how to update this probe. In the future, the DAPLink firmware will certainly support new target microcontrollers, and I want to be prepared :-)

Comment: You seem to be coming at this from a mistaken perspective - DAP doesn't support new target microcontrollers, the host PC software does (that's the whole point - it is a "low level" adapter that keeps all the target knowledge on the PC).  Anyway, you ignored the question about how it currently identifies - figuring that out might be a clue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, thank you for this clarification (I'm pretty new to DAP and DAPLink). Nevertheless, I just want to know how to do the firmware upgrade. It just doesn't *feel* right I cannot do that.

Comment: Take that up with the vendor then...  Even though the subject is a development tool, the way you are approaching this and the fact that there isn't even a functional problem you are trying to solve by doing an update makes it an off-topic *usage* question, not an on-topic *engineering* one.  For all that is presently known, *any* of the listed images might work, or *none* of them.  Worst case, as previously mentioned, you have sources available to build your own firmware.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton,
I will try to contact them. In the meantime, let's hope someone solves this question here, because I'm not hopeful the ARM company will reply at all.

Comment: It's not ARM you need to contact, it's the vendor of of the poorly documented *product* which you purchased, l-tek

Comment: Hmmm... good idea. I'll try.

Comment: You say it currently works for you via OpenOCD.  You have no specific goal to achieve in changing it.  **IF IT AIN'T BROKEN DON'T TRY TO FIX IT**, or at least not unless you have some other solution for your SWD needs and this thing is just a curiosity to play with.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, I'm working in a startup company. We're developing a new IDE for microcontrollers. One of my tasks is to support all kinds of probes in the IDE. One of them is the SWDAP (see https://new.embeetle.com/#hardware/probes/swdap). It is my duty to explain to our users how they should upgrade their probe firmware. I can do it for most other probes, but this SWDAP is giving me a really hard time...

Comment: No, you still lack a *goal* in updating the firmware.  Until you have a sound reason to change the firmware (which would implicitly include something specific  to change it to) you should neither change the firmware nor instruct anyone else do so.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, I understand what you mean. I acknowledge that I don't have the urgent need *right now* to update the firmware. And I won't push anyone else to do it. The reasons for doing it nevertheless are twofold: (1) If ever I have the need in the future to update this specific probe, I want to know how. (2) I plan to build my own probe based on SWDAP (it's open-source), so at that point I will definitely need to flash the firmware to it.

Comment: The thing is, *you know how to change the firmware*.  What you don't know is what to "update" it *with*.  If you had an actual *need* to update the firmware you'd have a specific update file you thought would be both applicable and an improvement.  So you already know everything you need to know for the moment.  When someone gives you a file that is an improvement, you know how to use it.  Anything more you might be curious about should probably be pursued by a) learning to build the firmware from source b) understanding the CMSIS-DAP protocol and c) looking at USB enumeration/identity issues

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, you have a point. I currently try to find out why the `0254_lpc11u35__0x0000.bin` firmware is not working with OpenOCD. I opened an issue on the DAPLink GitHub page :-)

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton,
I think this question is already completely answered. I know now **how to update** the firmware. The problem with **the firmware itself** is a different thing. I've started a different question to get an answer on that issue (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465577/daplink-firmware-doesnt-operate-with-openocd). Unfortunately, I've got two folks claiming it's a duplicate. Why? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [mbed page](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/SWDAP-LPC11U35/) for the product:

> ### Reprogramming SWDAP
>
> When a new SWDAP is plugged in to your machine, it will not contain valid any firmware, and so will appear as a disk drive called "CRP Disabled" as.
>
> To program the SWDAP, follow these steps:
>
> - Open the drive, and delete the file called "firmware.bin"
> - Download the required image from the table above (or build your own using DAPLink project)
> - Copy the .bin file onto the "CRP Disabled" drive.
> - On Windows, replace firmware.bin with the above firmware
> - On Linux/Mac, use command: dd if={new_firmware.bin} of={firmware.bin} conv=notrunc
> - Unplug your SWDAP, and plug it back in
> - It should now appear as a disk drive called DAPLink
>
> **You can re-program your SWDAP at any time by plugging it in with the button held down.** This will cause it to appear as the "CRP Disabled" drive, at which point you can follow the steps above.

It would seem that you want to start at the highlighted step (my emphasis) and then begin the procedure at the top. The link to download the firmware is on the page linked at the top of this answer.

When you download the release*, you will see quite a few files:

[image]

The file naming format is:

[Version]_[Board Name]_[Target Name]_[Offset].bin

So you would pick the appropriate firmware file for both the board (LPC11U35) and the target that you are programming. For example if your target board is the [LPC812-LPCXpresso Board](https://www.nxp.com/design/microcontrollers-developer-resources/lpcxpresso-boards/lpc812-lpcxpresso-board:OM13053) you would select the `0254_lpc11u35_lpc812xpresso_0x0000.bin` file.

<sub>*Releases page: https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/releases . From the releases page, just scroll down a little bit until you see "> Assets" (right under the "notes" part) and expand that. You will see a download link for the release.</sub>

Comment: Except that none of the offered images are for the board on that page!  It's possible that the connections to the LPC11U35 are similar enough between the pictured boards and one of the debug+target boards with images listed that it might work, but this is at minimum a gross failure of product documentation.

Comment: The whole point of DAP is that it is target-agnostic - all target knowledge remains in the host PC, so it doesn't make any sense for there to be target-specific programmer images, unless those images are specific to how the programmer circuit is implemented on various programmer+target eval boards.

Comment: (It is possible that the principle difference is in how the programmer identifies itself, which may be more an issue of mbed doing funny things than a functional one)

Comment: Hi @RonBeyer, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is still unclear to me which prebuilt binary I should flash (see **EDIT** in my answer). Please enlighten me.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The link includes the appropriate firmware for the LPC chip the OP is asking about, take a look at the [Github link](https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/blob/master/README.md), open the "releases" and take a look, support for the LPC11U35 was added back in [release 0245](https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/releases/tag/0245). So the link is appropriate.

Comment: @RonBeyer - just because it's firmware for the chip on the board, doesn't mean it's firmware for the board in question.  **Which specific download on your linked page are you arguing is appropriate for the asker's board**?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see the confusion, I will update my answer...

Comment: "LPC11U35" is a *chip*. Not a board.  Again, which of the listed images is appropriate to the asker's board?   You don't know, because that information is not available on the page you linked to.  It's quite possibly any of them will work, but there's no information there to indicate that, or to indicate that they will not brick the board (though hopefully that is unlikely).

Comment: The board requires different firmware depending on the *target* that it is programming. Any of the `LPC11U35` firmwares will work, however the *appropriate* depends on what it is programming. I can't say specifically because the OP did not provide that information. So the appropriate firmware depends on both the DAPLink board (this one is LPC11U35 based) **and** the target board.

Comment: Thank you @RonBeyer, it starts to get a bit clearer now. You say: `When you download the release, you will see quite a few files.` However, I wonder how exactly to "download the release". Where is that "release"?

Comment: From the [releases page](https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/releases), just scroll down a little bit until you see "> Assets" (right under the "notes" part) and expand that. You will see a download link for the release.

Comment: "The board requires different firmware depending on the target that it is programming" the whole point of the DAP idea is that **it should not**.  It's possibly that mbed is doing something silly and making its USB identification target specific.  But the legitimate reason for a different firmware would be if the LPC11U35  is wired up in different ways when "captive" on eval boards with various targets.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't know what to tell you, but it does. Whether this is a poor design or not isn't really up to me. If you look at the target for the [LPC812](https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/blob/master/source/family/nxp/lpc812/target.c) you can see that there is some flash/ram region information stored there. Maybe instead of sending the linker file to the programmer, it is embedded in the firmware and that is why they need something specific to the target.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and RonBeyer, I am not sure about this, but perhaps the following could be true. The firmware might need to be *target-specific* if you want to use the drag-and-drop feature (drag a binary to the mounted "disk" and drop it to flash it to the target).
Maybe if you use OpenOCD, it will just work on any target chip - regardless of the specific firmware version. It's just a theory, but could it be true?

Comment: For drag and drop, sure, for CMSIS-DAP no.  If they're meaning this to have drag and drop that could be an explanation.  Hopefully the generic no-target would work work for all targets as a CMSIS-DAP.  But if it were me, I'd not change the firmware currently in there, unless I had a specific need that could not serve, and specific confidence that another version could.  Of course, having built a CMSIS-DAP and seen how slow that protocol is on hardware that can only do USB full speed, I'd probably not have bought this product to begin with.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and RonBeyer, thanks to both of you for all your help. I've tried to flash the generic binary `0254_lpc11u35_0x0000.bin` to my SWDAP probe. Unfortunately, I couldn't do it. Please read my edits in **2.3 Third try**. Thank you so much.