# DAPLink firmware doesn't operate with OpenOCD

Tags: arm, debugging, firmware, lpc, swd

***Why this is not a duplicate***
*Some people seem to think this question is a duplicate, but there is an important difference:*

- *The [How to update the SWDAP firmware?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465187/how-to-update-the-swdap-firmware) question is all about **how** to update the firmware to the SWDAP probe. In the end we got a solution. The purpose of that question is therefore fulfilled. (I've edited the conclusion-section of that question to clarify this).*
- *The question on this page is all about **what** firmware is being put on the probe - and more in particular - what is wrong with that firmware such that it malfunctions with OpenOCD.*

*Please take your time to read both questions completely (not just the titles) if you think this question is a duplicate.*

### 1. Intro

**1.1 SWDAP probe**
I'm experimenting with the SWDAP probe from ARM (see https://www.l-tek.com/web-shop/l-tek-swdap-interface/). This flash/debug probe supports all Cortex-M microcontrollers. It uses the SWD protocol instead of JTAG.

[image]

At first I had some trouble updating the probe's firmware, but that has been solved in my previous question (see [How to update the SWDAP firmware?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465187/how-to-update-the-swdap-firmware)). The firmware on the probe itself is named "DAPLink" (see https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink).

**1.2 My system**
My computer has following software:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- OpenOCD 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)

### 2. Test with original firmware

The probe arrived to me with some firmware on it. I've plugged the probe into my computer while holding down the reset button. This way, I could access `firmware.bin` and save a copy of it as a backup.

On the original firmware, the probe works perfectly with OpenOCD. This is my OpenOCD startup command:

```py
openocd -f probe_swdap.cfg  -f chip_stm32f767zi.cfg
        -s "C:/.../scripts" -c "init; reset halt"
```

<sub>Note 1: I've splitted the command over two lines for readability.
Note 2: **C:/.../scripts** represents the path to the **scripts** subfolder in my OpenOCD installation folder.</sub>

This is my `probe_swdap.cfg` file:

```py
# OpenOCD probe config file for SWDAP
source [find interface/cmsis-dap.cfg]
transport select swd
```

And here is my `chip_stm32f767zi.cfg` file:

```py
# OpenOCD config file for STM32F767ZI
source [find target/stm32f7x.cfg]
reset_config srst_only
```

After running the OpenOCD startup command (see above), I get the following output in my console:

```py
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swd
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.0
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x5ba02477
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: hardware has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: external reset detected
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08001848 msp: 0x20080000
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

This works perfectly. OpenOCD listens on port **3333** for GDB connections. So next thing I do is starting a GDB client and connect to OpenOCD. Then I can start flashing/debugging my target STM32F767ZI chip. All is well.

### 3. Test with newest v0254 firmware

I'll first say a word about the firmware name convention. You can download the latest firmware from the DAPLink GitHub page. The names have a specific meaning:

> `[Version]` _ `[Probe Chip]` _ `[Target Chip]` _ `[Offset]`.bin 
>   <sub>more info see [How to update the SWDAP firmware?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465187/how-to-update-the-swdap-firmware)</sub>

The `Probe Chip` must match the chip on the probe itself. For me, that's the LPC11U35. The `Target Chip` must only match the target chip if you're planning to use the drag-and-drop flashing feature. I'm just using OpenOCD, so this `Target Chip` field doesn't matter to me.

The v0254 version has a "general" `0254_lpc11u35__0x0000.bin` firmware, being "target-agnostic". As I'm not using the drag-and-drop flashing, this choice makes most sense to me. So I update the SWDAP probe with this firmware.

Unfortunately, OpenOCD crashes immediately:

```py
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swd
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Error: CMSIS-DAP command CMD_INFO failed.
```

I've used exactly the same OpenOCD startup command as before, with exactly the same config files. Something is wrong with the `0254_lpc11u35__0x0000.bin` firmware.

### 4. Test with v0253 firmware

There is no "general" `0253_lpc11u35__0x0000.bin` firmware. All are target-specific. But that doesn't matter because I'm not going to use the drag-and-drop feature anyway.

I chose `0253_lpc11u35_6lowpan_borderrouterethernet_0x0000.bin` and flashed it to my probe. I plug out the probe and plug it back in. Now I start OpenOCD with the same commands as before. I get the following output:

```py
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swd
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.10
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
```

In fact the output looks good. It's the exact same output I get with the original firmware up to the `Info : clock speed 2000 kHz` line. But after that line, OpenOCD stops. It doesn't hang, it just terminates (this is clear because I get a new prompt in my console).

Something else that I noticed is the `DAPLINK` drive showing up in my Windows file explorer:

[image]

That didn't happen with the original firmware, nor with v0254.

### 5. Test with v0252 firmware

For this test, I put the `0252_lpc11u35_tiny_0x0000.bin` firmware on my probe. I get the exact same output as with the v0253 firmware:

```py
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swd
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.10
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
```

OpenOCD terminates after the `Info : clock speed 2000 kHz` line (again).

Also this time, I notice the `DAPLINK` drive in my Windows file explorer as soon as I plug in the probe.

### 6. Conclusions

I conclude that:

- Original firmware works just fine with OpenOCD.
- Firmware `0254_lpc11u35 ... .bin` is plain dead. OpenOCD crashes immediately.
- Firmware `0253_lpc11u35 ... .bin` is half-dead. OpenOCD terminates after outputting a few good lines. Also a `DAPLINK` drive appears in Windows.
- Firmware `0252_lpc11u35 ... .bin` reacts just like v0253.

I think firmware v0254 is defunct. But I don't want to jump into conclusions about firmware v0253 and v0252. Perhaps I need to issue a different startup command in OpenOCD to get them working? Or maybe I need to change something in my probe's config file?

Comment: You have done a great job of documenting your problem, but wouldn't it be best to contact L-Tek about their probe? It sounds like your problem is very specific to that device and its firmware. Also, I would try using a different computer to see if your drivers  or OpenOCD have somehow gotten corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the SWDAP firmware?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465187/how-to-update-the-swdap-firmware)

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson, I understand you point about the duplicate. I've edited the other question to differentiate it better from this one. I've also added the section **7. Why this is not a duplicate** in this question to explain the difference better. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson, I've already tried to contact L-Tek, but they did not yet respond. However, the probe L-Tek made is completely based on the open-sourced hardware project from ARM: the SWDAP project (see https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-HDK/tree/master/Production%20Design%20Projects/ARM-mbed/DAPLink/SWDAP). Along with this open-source hardware, ARM also provides the open-source firmware DAPLink (https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink) to run on that hardware. Both should operate seamlessly together.

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson, my drivers of OpenOCD are fine. Everything works with the original firmware on the SWDAP probe. And other probes (Black Magic Probe, STLink, ...) all work perfect with OpenOCD too. So it has to be the new DAPLink firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `pyOCD`? It works flawlessly with `DAPLink`, has great support and community directly on `GitHub`, it is written in `Python`, works on any platform, can utilize modular approach of `CMSIS Pack Manager` to support hundreds of targets just by downloading their specifications, can Debug MultiCore, can Flash rapidly using `FlashAlgo` skipping pages that does not need rewrite, and it is optimized to work with `DAPLink`. It works out of the box on anything that has `Python` `Virtualenv` no compilation required (or is done in the background by `pip`). Why do you even bother with `OpenOCD` and something that was not really meant there? Do you still script with `TCL` in a binary `C` based application? Can you understand how much power you get when all application is written in `Python` and you can reuse anything as module in your own application? I have used `OpenOCD` along with `UrJTAG` and even developed `LibSWD` around 2009..2013 but `DAPLink`+`pyOCD` feels like next generation tool we even did not dream about back then. You may also try the `ARM MBED-OS` :-)

- https://www.mbed.com/
- https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os
- https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD
- https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink
- https://github.com/ARMmbed/cmsis-pack-manager
- http://openocd.org/
- http://urjtag.org/
- https://github.com/CeDeROM/LibSWD
- https://github.com/CeDeROM/iCeDeROM
- https://www.python.org/
- https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages

Comment: This is a giant tangential *comment* rather than an answer to the question asked.  Do you have any actual evidence or reason to believe pyOCD would yield a different result?  Remember, **the asker's probe worked just fine with OpenOCD** using the original firmware, the issue only arose when they foolishly insisted on reflashing it with something else having less than clearly documented functionality and promising no apparent benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Negative. There is a lot of confusion in this thread. First of all the DAPLink is "the original" firmware and the problem may indicate a regression in recent release. Second of all, no question is asked if DAPLink works with OpenOCD, just a statement that it does not, which may imply false assumption that it does not work at all, which is then negated with an incomplete statement that it "may" work with an older release, which is neither a statement nor question, more like a comment with unclear goal. I would suggest if it does not work fix it and send the patches over GitHub :-)

Comment: Third of all, DAPLink is actively developed by ARM MBED team that also develops DAPLink and MBED-OS, so this is part of the same ecosystem used by thousands of people around the world as well as amazingly complex CI infrastructure to test every single firmware change on a hundreds of a real world hardware, so yes this is actual evidence that DAPLink+pyOCD works flawlessly. You are provided with references to try out yourself all is Free-and-Open-Source-Software :-)

Comment: Long story short: you are trying to use "wrong tools together", do not fight with DAPLink+OpenOCD, try the DAPLink+pyOCD and have fun! :-)

Comment: Also @ChrisStratton I would kindly ask you not to put -1 on a subject you don't understand because you don't understand it :-) The guy is trying to measure voltage with amperemeter :-)

Comment: To correct *your* misunderstanding of the situation, you'll need to read the asker's previous question.  **The probe worked just fine with "the original firmware".**  The issue only arrises after flashing with something there is no evidence to suggest is appropriate.  Presented with a list of download files and no guidance, *they merely guessed* and tried one - with no specific goal whatsoever.  The result is that something that used to work, no longer does.  When they reverted to the original firmware it worked fine.  You may prefer a different tool, but you have not answered the question.

Comment: Further, when you've read the original question, you'll discovered that the problem they are trying to "solve" is not a real one - rather, they are writing user guides for specific tools, so even if OpenOCD weren't the perfectly common and reasonable choice that it actually is, it's apparently on the list of software they are tasked to support, and so not something they have a free choice to discard.

Comment: "Because it is optimized for pyOCD and tested for pyOCD". I have developed both OpenOCD and DAPLink/pyOCD. If you have time, sure you can play. But there is far better tool right next to you that you can simply use in order to create something new, more advanced, and learn a lot more. I have provided a solution to a problem, up to you what you make out of it. Take care :-)

Comment: Nope, you've expressed a *tangential personal opinion* **while ignoring the asker's actual problem.**

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and CeDeROM, please stop fighting. Both of you have a point. **(1)** Technically speaking, this answer doesn't solve the problem. I will still look out for a solution with OpenOCD. **(2)** Nevertheless, this answer **is very useful** to me. We will at some point add PyOCD to our new IDE, and I am grateful for CeDeROM his efforts to list all the PyOCD resources and the clear overview of *OpenOCD vs PyOCD*. A big **thank you** to Mr. CeDeROM and a big fat +1 on your answer!

Comment: Hi @CeDeROM, I have one more question about PyOCD. Is there a PyOCD **standalone executable** that can run on a Windows/Linux machine without Python installed? The picture I've go in my mind is a standalone Embeetle IDE (the free IDE we're making) running on the user's computer, invoking a standalone PyOCD executable when the user clicks the "Flash" button. The two are independent softwares interacting with each other. The same like now: Embeetle IDE invokes a standalone OpenOCD and interacts with it.

Comment: You are welcome @K.Mulier glad you like the hints hope you enjoy the pyOCD :-) Yes it is possible to convert Python program into a binary, but that would mean a bundle with application plus python interpreter anyway for each pltform. This is why I recommended providing a Python interpreter, which is usually a part of the system already, then create devicated Python Virtual Environment for your application inside your working environment. This way you could use many more Python scripts not only binaries :-) See iCeDeROM which was supposed to be python based swiss army knife workbench :-)

Comment: pyOCD is a Python Module. No need to compile and solve OS dependencies in order to build and run (I have worked on OpenOCD and UrJTAG port for  FreeBSD). Python Module means that you only need to have `python` and `pip` installed on your OS, then `pip install pyocd` will build the application with all necessary dependencies, as simple as that. If you don't want to modify the OS, you create a dedicated `virtualenv MyPyVEnv`, then activate it with `activate MyPyVEnv/bin/activate` that will get you to a shell inside - this allows you to test and mess up everything without messing up the OS :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer with 3 more references to Python, Python Virtual Environment, and WIKI on how well Python integrates with other programming languages. You can include Python interpreter inside your (let's say) C or C++ application, or how to manage such binary applications form Python :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much @CeDeROM for explaining me all these things. Your answer and comments contain valuable information and resources that will definitely help me when the time comes we will put **PyOCD** into Embeetle (to work alongside **OpenOCD**). Perhaps we can give the user some kind of switch to select the one or the other for flashing (and debugging). Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the following reply from Antonio Borneo per mail:

> Hi Kristof,
>
> I have seen the messages about the daplink issue, but without the
>   adapter I though I cannot do that much, so I dropped it.
>
> I have read again all the threads (very quickly, I have to admit) and
>   also downloaded the daplink code from
>   https://github.com/armmbed/DAPLink It is a special implementation of
>   CMSIS-DAP for mbed.
>
> The original FW you had in your board was a `v0244` or older, because
>   OpenOD recognizes it as `Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.0` This string
>   has been changed in DAPLink FW file `source/daplink/cmsis-dap/DAP.c`
>   with commit
>   https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/commit/48417e9f8541f51bf2ca2e26a7ee69c5fcb34b80 
>   so the newer FW you have tested `v0252` and `v0253` report `Info :
>   CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.10` and both do not work with OpenOCD. I
>   don't have a `cmsis-dap v1.10` to verify if there is already something
>   wrong in OpenOCD.
>
> The DAPLink FW `v0254` adds many changes. Between them it stops
>   reporting the CMSIS-DAP version `"1.10"`, reporting instead the DAPLink
>   version `"0254"`.
>
> Checking the code of DAPLink, looks like it is possible to recompile
>   it for STM32F103 (ST-Link)! Maybe I will have a look at it using an
>   old Nucleo board, but it will depends on my spare time.
>
> Or maybe some other OpenOCD developer could take this reply as a hint.
>   Antonio

It doesn't completely solve the problem yet, but it gives valuable hints. Thank you @Antonio.